# Export the richtext content into excel/csv as it is

Tags: richtextbox, rich-text-editor, richtext, richtextediting

I have a form with multiple fields like textbox, email, radio and richtext editor. Multiple submissions are going to happen on the form. I want to export the submitted records list to an Excel or csv file keeping the richtext content as html content. for example, In richtext i entered "**Hello I am bunny**" in bold that means it's internal content is "`<strong>Hello I am bunny</strong>`". so While exporting to excel I want the richtext content as "**Hello I am bunny**".
Is there any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the string using regex. I posted an example to explain what I mean.

```
    Regex startTag = new Regex(@"<\w+>");

    List<string> tagWords = new List<string>();
    tagWords.Add("<strong>Hello I am bunny</strong>");
    tagWords.Add("<i>Hello this text is italic</i>");
    tagWords.Add("<small>Hello this text is small</small>");

    foreach (string item in tagWords)
    {
       Match start = startTag.Match(item);
       Console.WriteLine(item.Substring(start.Length,item.Length-start.Length*2)-1));
    }
```

Once you have the parsed string you should be able to just export it to the excel file.

Output is posted below, let me know if you need anymore help :)

[image]